# Hydrogen wave function for electron orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am a little confused about the quantum mechanics wave function. Hydrogen has a single electron in the first shell n=1, in the first subshell 1s with positive spin. In the attachment the wave function is represented for each unique quantum number n,l,m where n is the respective shell, if the electron only can exist in the first shell n=1 how is it possible to determine a probability density to find the electron in the other shells? Is that because the electron can get 'excited' into the other shells for a very short time?

Sorry if my question seems odd, I have a hard time grasping these new concepts!

[image: Hydrogen Wave Function]

Answer (score 2):

When the one electron is in the $n=1$ shell the atom is said to be in the ground (lowers energy) state.

That one electron can be in one of the other shells and you would then have an excited atom.

So the one electron could occupy any one of the shells and the diagrams show the probability of the electron being at a particular location within the shell it is occupying.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not odd, it just seems you're having a little bit of trouble letting go of the classical view on this problem.

The thing is, the hydrogen atom has only one electron by definition, but the state of this electron is represented by a superposition of the time-independent Schrödinger equation solutions, namely the "wave-functions" that are in your image. They are not the real wave-functions, they are the hamiltonian eigenstates. That is,

$$
H \, \psi_{n,m,l} = E_{n} \, \psi_{n,m,l}
$$

where $\psi_{n,m,l}$ are the functions in your image.

Now, the state of the electron in the hydrogen atom is

$$
\Psi(\vec{r},t) = \sum_n \, c_n \, \psi_{n,m,l} \, e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}
$$

The electron is not in the state $n=1$, but in fact in a superposition of all values for $n$, so it could be in $n>2$ states. So it has a non-zero probability of being in any other states $n > 1$.

It's also worth mentioning the wave-function collapse phenomenon. Let's say you make a measurement and find $n=2$, then the wave-function collapses and the electron is now in the $\psi_{2,l,m}$ state, although it wasn't prior to the measurement.

Answer (score -2):

And the probability is harmonic and symmetrical given that's only in four dimensions and it's not in a black hole typically when photons are in superposition It's relatively 60 /40 ratio. And this is based off of experimental . Is your based off the experiments of scientists that distant galaxies to confirm they weren't super position and those experiments detailed us 60/40 result 60% of the time they would be in superposition anything that's got the Symmetry like those hydrogen atoms hello energy mode